# How to load data in a (1.5) angular component?

Tags: angularjs

I'm able to get a basic component working, but trying to load some data via $http (users.get()) which returns a promise (the data does show up in console.log(this.data). But the data is not making it to the component template. Why?

```
.component('mrcUserInfo', {
bindings: {
    email: '<',
    first_name: '<',
    last_name: '<'
},
templateUrl: 'components/userInfo.html',
controller: function(users) {
    var scope = {};
    scope.thisId = 1;
    this.miketest = 'this is miketest';

    users.get(scope) // basically does a $http()...
    .then(function(data) {
        this.data = data.data;
        this.email = data.email;
        this.miketest = 'this is mike 2';

        console.log('user?');
        console.log(this.data);
    });
}
```

And my template has this

```
this is userInfo.html:
{{ $ctrl.miketest }}
```

The template displays 'this is miketest' but it does NOT display 'this is mike 2'

Any clues appreciated. Thanks. Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful when using `this`, especially in asynchronous code. In your specific case, `this` will be `window` object in your callback, so you're actually setting `miketest` variable on window rather than controller.

You can either do:

```
var ctrl = this;
users.get(scope) // basically does a $http()...
  .then(function(data) {
    ctrl.data = data.data;
    ctrl.email = data.email;
    ctrl.miketest = 'this is mike 2';

    console.log('user?');
    console.log(ctrl.data);
  });
```

Or explicitly bind `this`:

```
users.get(scope) // basically does a $http()...
  .then(function(data) {
    this.data = data.data;
    this.email = data.email;
    this.miketest = 'this is mike 2';

    console.log('user?');
    console.log(this.data);
  }.bind(this));
```

Additionally, if you're using something like [BabelJS](https://babeljs.io/), and are able to use modern JavaScript features, you can use double arrow functions to bind `this` to lexical scope:

```
users.get(scope) // basically does a $http()...
  .then((data) => {
    this.data = data.data;
    this.email = data.email;
    this.miketest = 'this is mike 2';

    console.log('user?');
    console.log(this.data);
  });
```